# What is a Vexed Word™?

Tags: pattern, geometry, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Vexed Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Vexed Words™ | Not Vexed Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| JOTTED | DENOTED |
| TOGA | SKIRT |
| QUILLS | PENS |
| ULNA | FEMUR |
| ZINC | IRON |
| FLOUTED | BRAGGED |
| CHUTES | LADDERS |
| CATION | ANION |
| TACKY | STICKY |
| EXCITE | DEPRESS |
| ABOUT | AROUND |
| SCREW | BOLT |
| MOTH | FLAME |
| VERB | ADVERB |
| PYREX | PLATE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Vexed Words™, Not Vexed Words™
JOTTED, DENOTED
TOGA, SKIRT
QUILLS, PENS
ULNA, FEMUR
ZINC, IRON
FLOUTED, BRAGGED
CHUTES, LADDERS
CATION, ANION
TACKY, STICKY
EXCITE, DEPRESS
ABOUT, AROUND
SCREW, BOLT
MOTH, FLAME
VERB, ADVERB
PYREX, PLATE
```

First Puzzle, enjoy!

Edit:  Added geometry tag post-solve

Comment: How much efforts did you add to create this one! Phew..Have tried almost everything I have in my head. Would be an interesting answer.

Comment: Can each word be tested whether it is a Vexed Word™ without relying on the other words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vexed Words™ are ...

> words whose letters on a QWERTY keyboard, connected by lines in order of appearance, form a single (usually looping) path that does not cross itself.
>
>  EXCITE forms a full loop, ending where it started, but doesn't cross its own path.

Not Vexed Words™ ...

> either cross  their path, or require doubling back so that it's not a single "curved" path, either all convex or concave.

They're called Vexed because ...

> Their paths are conVexed?  Best guess I have.

Comment: +1 I tried QWERTY but didn't knew I was forming a pattern.

Comment: Why *Vexed*? Because they are difficult to type? :-/

Comment: Forgot to add an explanation of the title; thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! :) Would add +1 for that as well

Comment: Correct!  And you got it before I added the 'geometry' tag, great work!  The title comes from the fact that since none of the interior angles of the loop are over 180 degrees, the loop traces a 'Convex Hull' about the letters.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Thanks - that was a fun one.  I eyed it for quite a while before getting it.  "Convex Hull" eh - I knew what was going on, but had no idea how to describe it... thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: How did you even figure this out ._.